# Sass loop: start from second instance of this element

Tags: sass, mixins

I have a series of divs in a step type layout. I am learning to use Scss at the moment and I thought maybe a mixin could work through the 12 divs and arrange them for me. So far I've got:

```
@mixin steps(){
    $stepBlocks: 12;

    @for $i from 1 through $stepBlocks {
        .steps-#{$i} {
            position: absolute;
            top: (($i * 296) + px);
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my div structure looks like:
[image]

I've made a HTML mockup as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/vdecree/CGGyL/

As you can see, the fiddle works fine, however how can I negate the effect of the first one? I need the first element to be `top: 0;` is there an `if` statement I can use? If you think you've a better way in which I can do this, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: 296 seems like a pretty arbitrary number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're likely wanting to is start with an offset of 0, rather than 296px.

```
@mixin steps(){
    $stepBlocks: 12;

    @for $i from 1 through $stepBlocks {
        .steps-#{$i} {
            position: absolute;
            top: ($i - 1) * 296px;
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```